# How to identify Duplicate Timestamps and delete duplicate that has NA

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series

I Have a dataframe as follows, I have inputted extra timestamps to so I can insert NAs where there was no timestamp available. However not all timestamps in the original data were at :52 seconds, therefore duplicates have no arisen just one second or so apart.

I would like to be able to find the instances where there are two entries for a given minute, and then mark these rows as either drop or keep in a separate column.

This would be based on keep = data available in the values columns (input, output), drop = the row with nas.

```
             datetime        output     input         m 1       m2
1   2012-01-01 12:00:52        NA        NA        24.42250    24.37881
62  2012-01-01 12:00:53     24.92     20.93        24.92000    24.92000
2   2012-01-01 12:01:52        NA        NA        24.60500    24.55069
63  2012-01-01 12:01:53     24.35     21.23        24.35000    24.35000
3   2012-01-01 12:02:52        NA        NA        24.78750    24.72320
64  2012-01-01 12:02:53     24.81     22.35        24.81000    24.81000
4   2012-01-01 12:03:52     24.97     22.18        24.97000    24.97000
5   2012-01-01 12:04:52        NA        NA        25.05500    24.98035
```

Comment: How did you add NA? Instead of removing duplicates if might be easier to add NA lines for missing minutes.

Comment: `ts <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:52",'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

`as.POSIXct("2017-12-01 23:59:52",'%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), by="min")`

`ts <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt("2012-01-01 00:00:52"), as.POSIXlt("2017-12-01 23:59:52"), by="min")`

`ts <- as.POSIXct(ts,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

`df <- data.frame(fldDate=ts)`

`anm_total <- full_join(df,anm_total, by = "fldDate")`

Comment: @ChrisPage wouldn't an easier solution be to simply drop rows that contain NAs with ```drop_na()``` from the ```dplyr``` package or similiar?

Comment: @Fnguyen I would only like to drop rows with NA values where there is a duplicated datetime. I would like a row for each minute intervals. But where there is no original data I would like the row to have nas.

Comment: So try to round all the dates to minutes, to skip the seconds, and then the `full_join` should do the job